# Figuring out the radius from chord or arc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Are you able to figure out the radius of a circle by any chord and or arc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure no... My intuition tells me you would also need at least a second arc/chord and or an angle

Comment: Yes, provided that chord happens to be the diameter of that circle.

Answer (score 1):

Any three non-collinear points through which a circle passes uniquely determine the circle.  So a chord is not enough, since the chord gives you just the two endpoints on the circle.  If you know all the points on an arc, that would determine the circle; if you know just the endpoints it would not.

Comment: To add, it would be possible to find the unique circle given, say, the length of a chord and its subtended arc, or the curvature of the arc, or the length of the arc and its sagitta.